# What are the small white dots in an onion cell seen under an electron microscope?

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, homework, microscopy, organelle

We had to use an electron microscope in class for an assignment and used onion cells. On the 40x and 100x magnification there are tiny white dots and I was wondering if someone could tell me what they are? I have to draw them up and label what I can see but i'm just not sure and I don't want to do it wrong. I saw something that said it could be granules of inclusion but i'm thinking it is probably bacteria or air pockets? I was also wondering if someone could tell me what these bean shaped things are? Or any other organelle that you might see, it would be very appreciated!

I'm sorry the photo isn't great, I could only add one photo and I struggled to find one that showed everything that I was asking, so I hope you can see the tiny white dots I mentioned in my question.

[image]

Comment: *We had to use an electron microscope in class* — do you mean a light microscope?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: Are you sure you were using an electron microscope?  They're quite complicated (and expensive (average $294,000, per Google), and generally used for much higher magnifications.  I also think you need specially treated specimens, not just a slice of onion.  To this non-expert, those white spots look like thin places in your sample, seen in a light microscope.